# How can I pass all command line arguments through Clap to another program?

Tags: command-line, rust, clap

I have a program `foo` that uses [Clap](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap) to handle command argument parsing. `foo` invokes another program, `bar`. Recently, I decided that users of `foo` should be able to pass arguments to `bar` if they like. I added the `bar` command to Clap:

```
let matches = App::new("Foo")
    .arg(Arg::with_name("file").value_name("FILE").required(true))
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("bar")
            .value_name("[BAR_OPTIONS]")
            .short("b")
            .long("bar")
            .multiple(true)
            .help("Invoke bar with these options"),
    )
    .get_matches();
```

When I try to pass the command `"-baz=3"` to `bar` like so:

```
./foo -b -baz=3 file.txt
```

or

```
./foo -b "-baz=3" file.txt
```

`clap` returns this error:

```
error: Found argument '-b' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

How do I tunnel commands through Clap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value of argument `bar` may itself start with a hyphen, then you need to set the [`allow_hyphen_values`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.allow_hyphen_values) option:

```
let _matches = App::new("Foo")
    .arg(Arg::with_name("file").value_name("FILE").required(true))
    .arg(
        Arg::with_name("bar")
            .value_name("[BAR_OPTIONS]")
            .allow_hyphen_values(true)
            .short("b")
            .long("bar")
            .multiple(true)
            .help("Invoke bar with these options"),
    )
    .get_matches();
```