# Is it possible to configure argument groups of unknown size with Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

I'm building a CLI which can call other underlying programs, that have their own options and arguments. I'd like to be able to pass those options to a program through the CLI.

```
$ cli --program [PROGRAM] --programOpts[OPT1, OPT2, ...]
```

Example:

```
$ cli --program foo --programOpts.bar 'foo' --programOpts.foo 'bar'
```

^ In this case `bar` and `foo` in `programOpts` are unknown to `cli`. The CLI only knows about `programOpts` and that it's an unknown vector of options specific to the underlying program that's being called.

I was hoping Clap had an API to implement such a thing (looked into `Arg` and `ArgGroup`) but it doesn't seem like it.

Is there such an API?

Comment: Does it work if you say that your argument is a `Vec`?

Comment: Take a look at `clap::Values` [here](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.Values.html), if you cannot assume that the values are encoded with UTF-8, use `clap::OsValues`.

Comment: @FrederikDS that however will end up with a different API: --opts 'one' 'two' 'tree'.

I was looking for: --opts.one 'foo' --opts.two 'bar'  where 'one' and 'two' aren't known

Comment: As a user of CLI tools, I'd be surprised by the `--programOpts.bar 'foo'` syntax. I would rather expect something like `--programOpts 'bar=foo'`.

Comment: See also [How can I pass all command line arguments through Clap to another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54191836/155423)

Comment: @SirDarius it actually seems quite common to have option.property syntax in CLI commands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I decided to go down a slightly different path and rather take advantage of the known UNIX `--` syntax.

Meaning that all options and flags coming after `--` will be passed down to the underlying program:

```
$ cli --program [PROGRAM] -- foo bar --bazinga --yay=w00t
```

This can be done using Clap's `.raw()` configuration on Arg structs.